# Is there always true predicate?

Tags: predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

Is there such predicate $P(x)$ where the statement is always true, for whatever the $x$ is?

Comment: $(x=x)$........

Comment: Who says that $x$ even needs to appear in a predicate?  Just like how $f(x)=5$ is a perfectly valid function (*it represents a horizontal line at height $5$*), so too is $P(x) \equiv \text{True}$ a perfectly valid predicate.  The predicate "$\text{True}$" is always true for every value of $x$.

Comment: See also: [Tautology (logic) on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

Answer (score 1):

Some (not all) presentations of first-order logic include as primitive symbols "$\top$" and "$\perp$," for "truth" and "falsity" respectively as primitive logical symbols - on the same level as $=$, $\forall,\exists$, and the Boolean connectives and parentheses. *(They can be thought of as nullary relation symbols, similarly to how constant symbols can be thought of as nullary function symbols, but since they're included as part of the **logical** language this isn't necessarily a helpful interpretation.)*

The formula "$x=x$" also does the job, although the situation there may be more complicated in [certain nonclassical logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/). Similarly, formulas like "$P(x)\vee\neg P(x)$" will work in classical logic, and formulas like "$\neg P(x)\vee \neg\neg P(x)$" will work even in intuitionistic logic. Because things do get more complicated when we leave classical logic, I tend to prefer including $\top$ and $\perp$ as logical primitives; but as long as we stay in the context of classical logic, it's unimportant.